# Recursive Descent precedence parsing missing prefix expression

Tags: algorithm, parsing, operator-precedence, recursive-descent

I'm building a simple language parser, and having an issue with lower precedence prefix expressions. Here's an example grammar:

```
E = E5
E5 = E4 'OR' E4 | E4
E4 = E3 'AND' E3 | E3
E3 = 'NOT' E3 | E2
E2 = E1 '==' E1 | E1
E1 = '(' E ')' | 'true' | 'false'
```

However, this grammar doesn't work correctly for the `NOT`, if it's used as the RHS of a higher precedence infix operator, i.e.:

```
true == NOT false
```

This is due to the `==` operator requiring E1 on the RHS, which cannot be a NOT operation.

I'm unsure the correct way to express this grammar? Is it still possible using this simplistic recursive descent approach, or will I need to move to a more featured algorithm (shunting yard or precedence climbing).

Comment: Note that `true == (NOT false)` does parse, due to the explicit parenthesis rule that restarts the evaluation from the top level.

Comment: Maybe use polish notation?
`E = E5
E5 = 'OR' E4 E4 | E4
E4 = 'AND' E3 E3 | E3
E3 = 'NOT' E3 | E2
E2 = '==' E1 E1 | E1
E1 = '(' E ')' | 'true' | 'false'`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want not E == E to parse as though it were not (E == E), but E == not E to parse as though it were E == (not E). That's possible but weird. If that's actually what you want, please make it clearer in the question.

Comment: It's definitely weird, but that's the only logically valid way to parse `E == not E`.

Comment: Note - I've clarified and extended in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following input and expected parses are correct:

1. test 1

   - input: `true == NOT false`
   - output: `(true == (NOT false))`
2. test 2

   - input: `NOT true == false`
   - output: `(NOT (true == false))`
3. test 3

   - input: `NOT true == NOT false`
   - output: `(NOT (true == (NOT false)))`

Here's an (ANTLR4) grammar that does the trick:

```
grammar Expr;

e : e5;
e5 : e4 'OR' e5 | e4;
e4 : e3 'AND' e4 | e3;
e3 : 'NOT' e3 | e2;
e2 : e1 '==' e3 | e1;
e1 : '(' e ')' | 'true' | 'false';

S : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Parses ANTLR created:

## 1

[image]

## 2

[image]

## 3

[image]

Comment: Nice summary, and nice graphs! I can see how that works, and it shows me that I over simplified the example - if there were multiple infix precedence levels higher than the NOT, this breaks down. I'll accept the answer, but I've also opened a new stackoverflow question with a more advanced example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337000

Answer (score 0):

Your language is also (unnecessarily) ambiguous. Fixing that helps you fix this problem, too.

Here, `D` is shorthand for "disjunction", `C` for conjunction, `N` for negation, and `P` for primary, `E` for equality.

```
D = C | C 'OR'  D
C = N | N 'AND' C
N = E |   'NOT' N
E = P | P '=='  P
P = '(' E ')' | 'true' | 'false'
```

Comment: In curiosity: how is it ambiguous? Your solution would help, except that it changes the precedence. `==` is supposed to bind more tightly than `NOT`, where instead you have reversed that. `NOT 1==2` should parse as `NOT(==(1, 2))`, but yours will parse as `==((NOT 1), 2)`.

Comment: @ChrisLeishman: Yours is ambiguous when parsing `true AND true AND true`, it doesn't know how to group them. As for `==` binding more tightly, you can just fix that yourself... but I fixed it for you. Why the downvote? :(

Comment: The downvote was because it changed the grammar to not be what I was after. But you fixed that now. However, the grammar you have now will not work `E = P | P '==' P` means that a 'NOT' term cannot exist on the RHS of '==' (only '(', 'true' or 'false').

Comment: @ChrisLeishman: Do you have any guesses how to fix it yourself?

Comment: If I did, I wouldn't be asking :) Other than to consider moving to a different algorithm (shunting yard or precedence climbing perhaps).

Comment: @ChrisLeishman: Well, you clearly want `NOT` to be possible on the right side of `==`, so have you tried replacing `P '=='  P` with `P '=='  N`? What happens if you do?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe use polish notation?

```
E = E5
E5 = 'OR' E4 E4 | E4
E4 = 'AND' E3 E3 | E3
E3 = 'NOT' E3 | E2
E2 = '==' E1 E1 | E1
E1 = '(' E ')' | 'true' | 'false'
```

Comment: That's not helpful for parsing the stated grammar. `==` is supposed to be infix.