# Recursive Descent precedence parsing - matching lower precedence prefix expressions

Tags: algorithm, parsing, operator-precedence, recursive-descent

Note: this is a more detailed version of [Recursive Descent precedence parsing missing prefix expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282725)

I'm building a simple language parser, and having an issue with lower precedence prefix expressions. Here's an example grammar:

```
E = E8
E8 = E7 'OR' E8 | E7
E7 = E6 'XOR' E7 | E6
E6 = E5 'AND' E6 | E5
E5 = 'NOT' E5 | E4
E4 = E3 '==' E4 | E3 '!=' E4 | E3
E3 = E2 '<' E3 | E2 '>' E3 | E2
E2 = E1 '+' E2 | E1 '-' E2 | E1 '*' E2 | E1 '+' E2 | E1
E1 = '(' E ')' | 'true' | 'false' | '0'..'9'
```

However, this grammar doesn't work correctly for the NOT, if it's used as the RHS of a higher precedence infix operator, i.e.:

```
true == NOT false
```

This is due to the == operator requiring `E3` on the RHS, which cannot be a 'NOT' operation.

I'm unsure the correct way to express this grammar? Is it still possible using this simplistic recursive descent approach, or will I need to move to a more featured algorithm (shunting yard or precedence climbing).

Here are some examples that would need to parse correctly:

- input `true == 1 < 2`, output `==(true, <(1, 2))`
- input `1 < 2 == true`, output `==(<(1, 2), true)`
- input `NOT true == false`, output `NOT(==(true, false))`
- input `true == NOT false`, output `==(true, NOT(false))` ** doesn't work
- input `true < NOT false`, output `<(true, NOT(false))` ** doesn't work

I have attempted to alter the levels `E4`, `E3`, and `E2` to use `E5` on the RHS of the infix expression, as suggested in [Recursive Descent precedence parsing missing prefix expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282725) (i.e. `E3 '==' E5`, `E3 '<' E5`, etc). However this breaks the precedence between these levels, i.e. `true == 1 < 2` would be incorrectly `parsed as`<(==(true, 1), 2)`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a way, except for adding extra alternatives with the `NOT`. E.g.: `E4 = E3 '==' E3 | E3 '!=' E3 | E3 '==' 'NOT' E3 | E3 '!=' 'NOT' E3 | E3` etc.

Comment: That would get crazy, given `NOT` wouldn't be the only prefix expression (i.e. also `-`, `+`, etc)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Hence the start of my sentence "I don't see a way", and the fact that I didn't post the suggestion as an answer :)

Comment: This is a language you are defining yourself, right? With your outline above, the relational operators, like `==` bind harder than the logical operators, like `AND`. That makes something like `A AND B == C AND D` parse like `A AND (B == C) AND D` - is that what you want? I think you probably want the relational operators at the top.

Comment: The standard practice is to make prefix unary operators have the second highest precedence (and postfix unaries should have the highest precedence). It doesn't make much sense to define them differently, for this exact reason.

Comment: Ok... however I do want a higher precedence for boolean operators, like `NOT`, than comparison operators like `==`. And interestingly, this is not a logical problem: it's clear how the variations should be parsed. The issue is finding an algorithm that achieves it.

Comment: Er, did you try what I told you on your last question? (Replacing `P '=='  P` with `P '=='  N`.) You should mention what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

When sticking to the way your language is defined, you cannot have

```
true == NOT false
```

as a valid term in your language. Because then

```
NOT false == true
```

would be ambigous: the parse tree could be either

```
    NOT
     | 
    ==
   /  \
false true
```

or

```
   ==
  /  \
 NOT true
  |
false
```

Note that

```
true == NOT (false)
```

is a valid term in your language. A probably more intuitive definition of your language would be to put the `NOT`-level from `E5` down to `E2`. Then

```
true == NOT false 
NOT false == true
```

are both valid and `NOT` binds with `false`. And the alternative meaning of the second expression would be expressed as

```
NOT (false == true)
```

If these options still do not satisfy you, you have to change/extend the tool. E.g. the yacc/bison parser allows to explicitely define operator precedences; see e.g. [here](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_8.html#SEC71)

Comment: It's not ambiguous because of precedence: `==` always binds closer whenever possible. So `NOT false == true` _must_ parse as `NOT(==(false, true))`. The interesting issue is `false == NOT true`, as its _not possible_ for the `==` to be applied first, and so that must parse as `==(false, NOT(true))`.

Comment: to clarify: what you want (and your mind can do) and what your "tool" (the way you specify the language) is capable off are two different things. The way you specifiy your language does not allow to resolve the mentioned ambiguity. Your mind can - and other tools also; see my edit.

Comment: But also think about your language again: do you really want to allow `NOT 1`? (just because the C language allows this?) And to you really want to allow at most three `OR` operands in a row?

Comment: I'm happy to use different algorithms or approaches (the tool is not so important). Also, I do want to allow `NOT 1` to be _parsed_. That doesn't mean it's semantically correct - indeed I'd make this a type error, since `1` is not a boolean. But it has to be parsed before that can be determined.